# List brief information of HuaWei IOS

Tags: huawei

When I use `display interfaces` there shows many data. I have to use <kbd>Space</kbd> to skip pages to see more content.

```
Description:HUAWEI, AR Series, GigabitEthernet0/0/1 Interface
Route Port,The Maximum Transmit Unit is 1500
Internet protocol processing : disabled
IP Sending Frames' Format is PKTFMT_ETHNT_2, Hardware address is 00e0-fc8e-1f05
Last physical up time   : -
Last physical down time : 2018-10-23 15:37:15 UTC-08:00
Current system time: 2018-10-23 15:54:46-08:00
Port Mode: COMMON COPPER
Speed : 1000,  Loopback: NONE
Duplex: FULL,  Negotiation: ENABLE
Mdi   : AUTO
Last 300 seconds input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
Last 300 seconds output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
Input peak rate 0 bits/sec,Record time: -
Output peak rate 0 bits/sec,Record time: -

Input:  0 packets, 0 bytes
  Unicast:                  0,  Multicast:                   0
  Broadcast:                0,  Jumbo:                       0
  Discard:                  0,  Total Error:                 0

  CRC:                      0,  Giants:                      0
  Jabbers:                  0,  Throttles:                   0
  Runts:                    0,  Symbols:                     0
  Ignoreds:                 0,  Frames:                      0

Output:  0 packets, 0 bytes
  Unicast:                  0,  Multicast:                   0
  Broadcast:                0,  Jumbo:                       0
  ---- More ----
```

Is there any command for list brief information of HuaWei IOS's Interfaces?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but what about `display interface brief`?

Comment: it means display less information. you see upper, every one interface log much data.

Comment: You did ask *Is there any command for list brief information of HuaWei IOS's Interfaces?*

Comment: @Cown Yes, I want to list all Interfaces in one page.

Comment: I'm confused, did you try `display interface brief`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `display interface brief` command, you can view information about all the interfaces on the equipment, including the physical status, protocol status, bandwidth usage in the inbound and outbound direction during a certain period of time, and the numbers of sent and received packets with errors.

```
<Quidway> display interface brief
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
^down: standby
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(b): BFD down
(e): ETHOAM down
(d): Dampening Suppressed
InUti/OutUti: input utility/output utility
Interface                   PHY   Protocol InUti OutUti   inErrors  outErrors
Ethernet0/0/1               down  down        0%     0%          0          0
Ethernet0/0/2               down  down        0%     0%          0          0
Ethernet0/0/3               down  down        0%     0%          0          0
Ethernet0/0/4               down  down        0%     0%          0          0
Ethernet0/0/5               down  down        0%     0%          0          0
Ethernet0/0/6               down  down        0%     0%          0          0
Ethernet0/0/7               down  down        0%     0%          0          0
Ethernet0/0/8               down  down        0%     0%          0          0
Ethernet0/0/9               down  down        0%     0%          0          0
Ethernet0/0/10              down  down        0%     0%          0          0
```

Source: http://support.huawei.com/hdx/pages/SE0000502997DEA01271/01/SE0000502997DEA01271/01/resources/s/display_interface_brief.html